# Counting the longest consecutive run in a Coin Toss simulator

Tags: java

I am in a beginning Java programming class and one of our assignment is to write a program that simulates tossing a coin a user-specified number of times. The functional class, CoinToss.java, looks like this:

```
public class CoinToss {
  private char[] results;
  private int numHeads;
  private int numTails;
  private double headsFrac;
  private double tailsFrac;

  private int currentRun;
  private char currentOutcome;

  public CoinToss(int numTosses) {
     results = new char[numTosses];
     for(int i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        double number = Math.random();
        if(number < 0.5) {
           results[i] = 't';
        }
        else {
           results[i] = 'h';
        }
     }

  }

  public void count() {
     for(int i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        if(results[i] == 't') numTails++;
        else numHeads++;
     }
     headsFrac = (double)numHeads/results.length;
     tailsFrac = (double)numTails/results.length;
  }

  public double getFracHeads() {
     return headsFrac;
  }

  public double getFracTails() {
     return tailsFrac;
  }

  public char[] getTosses() {
     return results;
  }

  public void getLongestRun() {
     currentOutcome = 'h';
     for(int i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        if(currentOutcome == results[i]) {
           currentRun++;
        }
        else {
           currentOutcome = results[i];
           currentRun = 1;
        }
     }

     if(currentOutcome == 'h') {
        System.out.println("Longest run was " + currentRun + " heads.");
     }
     else {
        System.out.println("Longest run was " + currentRun + " tails.");
     }
  }
```

}

My main area of concern is the `getLongestRun()` method. The instructions say: Create a method that examines the array of coin tosses to locate the longest
possible run of heads or tails that were tossed. You will need two attributes,
these attributes have the current number of consecutive outcomes (a run) and
the outcome associated with the run (head or tail). In a loop, compare each toss
in the array to the outcome
of the current run. If they match, the current run is
now recognized as one longer. If they don’t match, then the current run has
ended. Compare the number of consecutive outcomes in this run that has just
ended with the largest number of consecutive outcomes that has been
previously seen
(the longest run so far). Whether or not this is a new longest
run, reset the current outcome to the one just examined and reset the length of
the current run to 1. Think about if any special processing needs to happen
when the loop terminates.

My main concern is how to get that method working correctly. It is not counting the longest consecutive number of heads or tails correctly.

Comment: Just a matter of style and nothing to do with the functionality, but in this case since you've only got two possibilities, you could easily use a boolean instead of a character. Best case scenario though would be to use an enum instead.

Answer (score 1):

You don't store the results of each run; you simply overwrite the previous value when a new run begins.  That means that your `getLongestRun()` method will only ever print the length of the *last* run, rather than the longest.

To fix this, you will need to record the results of each run in an array (or, preferably, an object structure like `ArrayList`) then traverse it to find the maximum value.  Alternatively, you could simply have a variable which always holds the maximum streak and simply discard the latest one if it's lower than the current maximum.

I won't provide full code for you since this is coursework, but here's a pseudocode (Pythonic) idea of what I mean:

```
current_streak = 0
longest_streak = 0
current_coin = coin_toss_list[0]
for coin in coin_toss_list:
    if current_coin == coin:
        current_streak = current_streak + 1
    else:
        if current_streak > longest_streak:
            longest_streak = current_streak
        current_streak = 1
        current_coin = coin
print "Longest streak was " + longest_streak
```

Comment: You only need to keep the maximum run, e.g. add `int longestHeadRun` and `int longestTailRun` to `getLongestRun()` and set them to `currentRun` before resetting that.